# How to change values in database at a specific time

Tags: django, database

I'm trying to **change values** of a column in a table in a database at a **specified time** without having to do it manually. Is there a way to achieve this? If yes, wouldn't mind an example or something.
Thanks!! :)

ps. I'm using django with sqlite (using sqlite just because it comes with django as a default and I'm still learning django)

Comment: You can create a Django management command that updates the database and start it at specific time with cron.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do

1. Install plugin for django scheduled tasks:[django-chronograph](https://code.google.com/archive/p/django-chronograph/).It should be really simple to create your schedule.
2. You will have to specify the linux command `./manage.py dbshell`. Then use your query as parameter
   Command reference: [django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/django-admin/)